# How can Singaporeans studying in a Western country protect themselves from racist hate crime?

Tags: safety

I am Malay but some Chinese and Indian friends also consider studying overseas.

We heard racist hate crimes are common in the West, like Indian students killed in Australia, shooting blacks in the USA and attacks on Muslims in Europe. Our literature text by David Hare shows British assault Indians. Even worse is attacking Chinese mistaken for Japanese or Sikhs mistaken for Muslims.

In Singapore, general crime rate is low and we are taught how to protect from crimes. Every country has racism but in Singapore it is milder than the West and hate crimes almost never happen here.

Of course tourists and international students also crime targets for non racist reasons. Advice on this is also welcome since how to protect from crimes in Singapore may not work overseas.

Comment: You've already posted this yesterday on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59052/how-can-singaporean-studying-in-western-country-protect-from-racist-hate-crime). Pelase [don't crosspost onto other stackexchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Did you not get what you wanted? You had several answers but haven't commented on any of them or accepted them.

Comment: On Travel.SE they voted to close because "studying abroad is not within the scope" of Travel.SE so they suggested I post on Expats.

Comment: ah yes, I see that now - I've voted to reopen. Ideally they'd have migrated it, rather than closing :/  It's so not a study question, the question is about safety while travelling. Were the answers there not suitable?

Comment: Can reopen the question? Can explain "too broad" and how to narrow the question? Would be spam if I post many separate questions for each Singaporean race and Western area.

Comment: Perhaps you could answer my questions above before we consider reopening? What was wrong with the answers you got on travel??

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think this is a realistic world view. I think studying abroad will show you that the world is a much nicer place outside of your country than what the media makes it out to be. That pretty much goes for all places on the world. Sure, things happen but the odds of it happening to you are incredibly low.

Source: personal experience after traveling in 5 continents. But it's not hard to do the statistics lookup yourself.

Comment: The most dangerous thing you can do abroad is to show fear and the expectation of crime. People tend to behave corresponding to your expectations. Your attitude may have very well helped you.